# Cimg, jpeglib и visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Никак не могу разобраться как заставить работать Cimg с  jpeg. Подключить всё подключил:

```
#include "jpeglib.h"
#define cimg_use_jpeg
#include "CImg.h"
```

Может я Jpeglib не так поставил? В `Каталоги включения`, `Каталоги библиотек` и `Дополнительные зависимости` кажется, правильно стоят. Но при сборке проекта выдаёт

```
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_std_error"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_CreateCompress"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_stdio_dest"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_set_defaults"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_set_quality"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_start_compress"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_write_scanlines"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_finish_compress"
1>message.image2.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "jpeg_destroy_compress"
1>C:\Progr\VK\message.image2\x64\Release\message.image2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 9
```

Comment: Вы просто не подключили lib файлы.

Comment: @KoVadim на самом деле, я подключал всё по инструкциям. Но действительно, ту же самую ошибку выдаёт даже если бы я ничего не подключал. Тут всё сложнее, lib файл, что я подключил, устарел

Comment: **кажется, правильно стоят** надо как то сделать, что бы было "точно правильно". И может ему нужна другая библиотека для jpeg? Каким мануалом Вы пользовались?

Comment: @KoVadim http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=399845